# ¿Cómo evito que una imagen recortada se descoloque cuando hago la pantalla de mi navegador más pequeña?

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando voltear una imagen usando propiedades de css que no sean transform o rotate. La imagen es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito tener algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De tal forma que entre cada icono de la imágen tenga esos textos.
He intentado hacerlo con margin bottom para recortar la imagen en tres partes y sólo aparezca la parte que me interesa. Ayudandome de la propiedad vertical-align:middle y de la propiedad overflow:hidden

De tal forma que me quede algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pasa es que cuando hago la pantalla de mi navegador más pequeña, se deforman las imagenes recortadas.

Mi HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">
    <title>Tarta de manzana</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
    <h1>Tarta de manzana</h1>
    <div>
        Esta era la receta de la tarta de manzana de mi abuela. Nunca he 
        visto otra igual. Siempre será mi favorita y he ganado varios primeros 
        premios en varias competiciones. ¡Espero que se convierta en una de 
        tus favoritas!
    </div>
    <div>
        1h 30 min <img src="../images/iconos_v.png">
        8 raciones <img src="../images/iconos_v.png">
        512 cals <img src="../images/iconos_v.png">
    </div>
    <div>
    <h2>Ingredientes</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>1 paquete de pasta de hojaldre doble para molde de 22cm</li>
        <li>1/2 taza de mantequilla sin sal</li>
        <li>3 cucharadas de harina común</li>
        <li>1/4 taza de agua</li>
        <li>1/2 taza de azucar blanca</li>
        <li>/2 taza de azucar morena</li>
        <li>8 manzanas golden peladas, sin corazón y en láminas</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="../images/iconos_v.png">
        <label>Prep<br><b>30</b> m</label>
        <span></span>
        <label>Cocinado<br><b>1</b> h</label>
        <span></span>
        <label>Listo en <br><b>1</b> h <b>30</b> m</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h2>Instrucciones</h2>
C. Derretir la mantequilla en un cazo. Agregue la harina hasta formar una pasta. Agregue el agua, el azúcar blanco y el azúcar moreno, y deje hervir. Reduzca la temperatura y deje hervir a fuego lento.</li>    <ol>
    <li>Precalentar el horno a 220º
    <li>Coloque la base de hojaldre en el molde. Rellene con manzanas, montadas entre si un poco para que resulte cubierta en forma de celosía. Vierta suavemente el resultado del paso anterior. Viertalo lentamente para que no se vaya por los bordes.</li>
    <li>Hornealo durante 15 minutos en el horno precalentado. Reduzca la temperatura a 175ºC. Continúe horneando de 35 a 45 minutos, hasta que las manzanas estén blandas.</li>
    </ol>
    </div>
    </main>
</html>
```

Mi CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');

/*---------------------------MAIN CONTAINER---------------------------------*/
body > main{
  max-width:50%;
  min-width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;

}
/*--------------------------HEADER-------------------------*/
h1:first-child{
  background-image: url('../images/tarta_manzana.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding-top:20%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:4.5vw;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


/*----------------------FIRST DIV--------------*/
body > main > div:nth-child(2){
  margin:30px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
/*----------------------SECOND DIV-----------------------*/

body > main > div:nth-child(3){
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

body > main > div:nth-child(3) > img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:50px;
  height:153px;
}

body > main > div:nth-child(3) > img:nth-child(1){
  margin-bottom: -105px;
}

body > main > div:nth-child(3) > img:nth-child(2){
    margin-bottom: -105px;
    margin-top:-105px;
}

body > main > div:nth-child(3) > img:nth-child(3){
  margin-top:-105px;
}
/*----------------THRID DIV--------------------*/
body > main > div:nth-child(4){
  margin:30px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right: 50px;  
  border-top:1px solid;

}
/*----------------FOURTH DIV----------------*/
body > main > div:nth-child(5){
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
body > main > div:nth-child(5) > img{
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: -8.8em;
  margin-top:-4.8em;
  margin-right:10px;
  text-align: center;
}
body > main > div:nth-child(5) > label:nth-child(2){
  position:absolute;
  bottom:60px;
  margin-left:10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body > main > div:nth-child(5) > b:nth-child(4){
  margin-left:300px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body > main > div:nth-child(5) > span:nth-child(3){
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 50px; 
  width: 1px;
  margin-left:80px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
body > main > div:nth-child(5) > label:nth-child(4){
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:30px;
    bottom:60px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}
body > main > div:nth-child(5) > b:nth-child(8){
  margin-left:2100px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body > main > div:nth-child(5) > span:nth-child(5){
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 50px; 
  width: 1px;
  margin-left:130px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
body > main > div:nth-child(5) > label:nth-child(6){
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:40px;
  bottom:60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
/*--------------FIVE DIV-------------*/
body > main > div:nth-child(6){
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-top:1px solid;
  margin:30px;
}
```

Comment: ¿Es parte de algún ejercicio o tarea? ¿No sería más fácil tener 3 imágenes y muestras u ocultas lo que desees según el ancho del navegador?

Comment: Es parte de una tarea, no puedo modificar la imagen. Debe estar al completo

Comment: Estos problemas en las redimensiones de pantalla tienen fácil solución usando bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Tengo que usar css puro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que las imágenes deben ir en un elemento contenedor, yo ocuparé `figure` para como contenedor padre de estas

```css
figure.icon{
  overflow:hidden;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  width:60px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
}

figure.icon > img{
  width:100%;
}

figure.icon.pie_chart > img{
  transform: translateY(-33.3333%);
}

figure.icon.bar_chart > img{
  transform: translateY(-66.6666%);
}
```

```html
<figure class="icon clock">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuZNM.png" />
</figure>

<figure class="icon pie_chart">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuZNM.png" />
</figure>

<figure class="icon bar_chart">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuZNM.png" />
</figure>
```

Si se observa bien el código, rápidamente uno pude concluir que estar repitiendo las imágenes es tedioso e innecesario, así que transformaremos todo el código anterior ahora usando `background-image` y la etiqueta `<i>` que si bien son para los texto en itálicas, el uso actual de facto es para iconos

```css
i.icon{
  overflow:hidden;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  width:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuZNM.png");
  background-position-x: 0;
  background-position-y: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

i.icon: after{
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}

i.icon.pie_chart{
  background-position-y: 50%;
}

i.icon.bar_chart{
  background-position-y: 100%;
}
```

```html
<i class="icon clock"></i>
<i class="icon pie_chart"></i>
<i class="icon bar_chart"></i>

<br>

<i class="icon clock" style="width:100px"></i>
<i class="icon pie_chart" style="width:100px"></i>
<i class="icon bar_chart" style="width:100px"></i>

<br>

<i class="icon clock" style="width:200px"></i>
<i class="icon pie_chart" style="width:200px"></i>
<i class="icon bar_chart" style="width:200px"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias cosas a tener en cuenta:

Lo primero, cuidado con el HTML, falta el cierre de la etiqueta `body`.

Luego, bastaría con que prescindieses de los márgenes que usas para corregir la posición en las imágenes y lo sustituyeses por las dimensiones que tendrá cada icono (en principio y según tu imagen, de 50x50px), la propiedad `object-fit: cover` y luego la propiedad  `object-position`, definiendo su valor según la posición de cada elemento en la imagen (`center top`, `center center` y `center bottom` respectivamente):

```
body > main > div:nth-child(3) > img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

body > main > div:nth-child(3) > img:nth-child(1) {
  object-position: center top;
}

body > main > div:nth-child(3) > img:nth-child(2) {
  object-position: center center;
}

body > main > div:nth-child(3) > img:nth-child(3) {
  object-position: center bottom;
}

body > main > div:nth-child(5) > img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center top;
}
```

En todo caso, te recomendaría que simplificases bastante el código CSS, abusas demasiado de selectores tipo `nth-child()` y a la larga te va perjudicar el mantenimiento de tus trabajos. Lo mejor sería utilizar alguna clase. Por ejemplo, en tu caso vas a utilizar los iconos varias veces, puedes crear un estilo específico para ello.

Comment: Muchas gracias, disculpa es que no me deja usar clases ni id en el trabajo! pero muy buen aporte!